# RSocket: How to handle fireAndForget message from server in Flutter

Tags: spring, flutter, dart, rsocket, spring-rsocket

I was trying handle message from server by using rsocket-dart package in Flutter
A Server send me message by fireAndForget

Server is Spring boot

Server Code:

`@Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000) public void push() { rSocketRequester .route("api.push") .data("some push message with id " + RandomUtil.getPositiveInt()) .send() .block(); }`

Is it possible handle messages like this?

Or is there analog Spring annotation @MessageMapping in dart?